# How to validate uniqueness of a field before save, if the field is changed before save?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a `User` model that needs to validate the uniqueness of a field before it is saved, this field however, is changed before it is saved (it is hashed). How can I do this? I tried the following: Adding a validate digest at the end of the before save call, but that doesn't work.

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord        
  has_secure_password
                                                
  before_save :downcase_email, :downcase_name, :digest_email, :validate_email_digest
                                                                             
  validates :email, format: { with: URI::MailTo::EMAIL_REGEXP }, presence: true 
  validates :name, length: { within: 2..40 }, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  validates :password_digest, presence: true
                                                               
  self.implicit_order_column = 'created_at'

  private     
                                   
  def validate_email_digest
    # This throws an exception                                  
    validates_uniqueness_of :email, message: 'That email is already in use.'
  end
  
  def downcase_email
    self.email = email.downcase
  end

  def downcase_name
    self.name = name.downcase
  end

  def digest_email
    self.email = Digest::SHA2.hexdigest(email).to_s
  end
end
```

How can I validate the result of the model `before_save` before they are saved to the database? In this case how can I validate that the digested email is unique after it's been digested by `before_save :digest_email`?

**The steps I'm looking to perform:**

1. Validate the emails form (ie: test it against email regexp)
2. Hash it
3. Then validate again that the hash is unique within the table

I would prefer to do this all with validations, and keep my controllers form having much logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So turns out for what I needed exactly I need to make a `validate` call and then verify the uniqueness that way. I used the following code:

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_secure_password

  before_validation :downcase_name, :downcase_email
  before_save :digest_email

  validates :email, format: { with: URI::MailTo::EMAIL_REGEXP }, presence: true
  validates :name, length: { within: 2..40 }, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  validates :password, presence: true, confirmation: true
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true, on: :create

  validate :verify_email_hash_uniqueness, on: :create

  self.implicit_order_column = 'created_at'

  private

  def downcase_email
    self.email = email.downcase
  end

  def downcase_name
    self.name = name.downcase
  end

  def digest_email
    self.email = Digest::SHA2.hexdigest(email).to_s
  end

  def verify_email_hash_uniqueness
    email_digest = Digest::SHA2.hexdigest(email).to_s
    errors.add(:base, 'Email is already in use') if User.where(email: email_digest).exists?
  end
end
```

This will test uniqueness AFTER it tests if the email is well formed, allowing me to hash emails before putting them into the database, verifying their form and uniqueness.